# How to get final Value in range Slider?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rangeslider

I'm using TT range slider(Double Slider) for filtering price in my app everything is working perfect but when my final price is some(for example 20) with out selection slider I'm clicking on apply button final price is not coming and the slider option is coming to 0 value if any Answers it would be Appreciated. Thanks in Advance.
My code

```
float price = [_filterpriceStr floatValue];

NSLog(@"%f",price);

if ([[GlobalVariables appVars].Apply isEqualToString:@"Apply"]) {

    float minimum = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"filtermin"] floatValue];
    float maxmum = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"filtermax"] floatValue];

    minValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"filtermin"];
    maxValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"filtermax"];

    //standard range slider
    self.rangeSlider.delegate = self;
    self.rangeSlider.minValue = 0;
    self.rangeSlider.maxValue = price;
    self.rangeSlider.step = price;

    self.rangeSlider.selectedMinimum = minimum;
    self.rangeSlider.selectedMaximum = maxmum;

    NSNumberFormatter *customFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    customFormatter.positivePrefix = @"£";
    self.rangeSlider.numberFormatterOverride = customFormatter;
    self.rangeSlider.tintColorBetweenHandles = [UIColor colorWithRed:15.0f/255.0f green:201.0f/255.0f blue:218.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

}
else
{
    float price = [_filterpriceStr floatValue];

    //standard rsnge slider
    self.rangeSlider.delegate = self;
    self.rangeSlider.minValue = 0;
    self.rangeSlider.maxValue = price;
    self.rangeSlider.selectedMinimum = 0;
    self.rangeSlider.selectedMaximum = price;

    NSNumberFormatter *customFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    customFormatter.positivePrefix = @"£";
    self.rangeSlider.numberFormatterOverride = customFormatter;
    self.rangeSlider.tintColorBetweenHandles = [UIColor colorWithRed:15.0f/255.0f green:201.0f/255.0f blue:218.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

}
```

when Apply Button Click

```
 [GlobalVariables appVars].PriceRange = @"PriceRange";


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:minValue forKey:@"filtermin"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:maxValue forKey:@"filtermax"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

NSLog(@"%@",maxValue);

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this delegate method with which you will get your min and max slider value.

```
 -(void)rangeSlider:(TTRangeSlider *)sender didChangeSelectedMinimumValue:(float)selectedMinimum andMaximumValue:(float)selectedMaximum{

NSLog(@" Min Value: %.0f Max Value: %.0f", selectedMinimum, selectedMaximum);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:selectedMinimum forKey:@"filtermin"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:selectedMaximum forKey:@"filtermax"];

 }
```

Comment: my problem is when my slider value is 0 to 20 then I click on apply button its going to 0 value

Comment: Don't  assigning Min and max value to slider when you press Apply. Just debug on your final apply  step by step and avoid repeat coding. you can simply get your min and max value from above methods. Just pass it for global, Thats it.

Comment: No its not working when I I'm selecting price its taking to final value and clcking on final value its taking some min value

Comment: Hi @santoshi Please check this simple demo. Its very clear and understandable. here is the link "we.tl/t-maHRfoW06y"

Comment: You need to change App identifier and developer certificates. All files are there please check.

Comment: Did you update pod files? If you r not able to do just share your code will help you

Comment: @can you give me your mail id? I will send to your mail id.

Comment: @can you please check your mail